# Core Data RelationShip Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

Tengo el siguiente ejemplo para poder entender las relaciones entre entidades en `Core Data`,(marca modelo), tengo marcas de automóviles respectivamente y ahora quiero agregar modelos a estas marcas de automóviles para esto he registrado en `vieDidLoad` algunas marcas y cuando elija una marca salda un `UIAlertViewController` donde me permitirá capturar un modelo para esta marca pero **no sé como relacionar este modelo a ese objeto creado con anterioridad**, suponiendo que fuera algo dinámico. Enseguida agrego mi código; los `id` de los objetos los guardo en un arreglo de `String` y ahora comparo con un `Predicate` pero el resultado que me devuelve sale con comillas. En el predicate del arreglo `Id[indexPath.row]`

con comillas en el predicate

```
* predicate: SELF == "0xd000000000040000<x-coredata://A94EA723-56E4-475B-8D1B-582FC4C58CCD/MARCA/p1>"
```

NSOBJECT sin comillas

```
*  predicate: SELF == 0xd000000000040000<x-coredata://A94EA723-56E4-475B-8D1B-582FC4C58CCD/MARCA/p1>
```

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  Audi
//
//  Created by MACBOOK on 28/04/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 mossito. All rights reserved.
//

    import UIKit
    import CoreData


    let appDelegado:AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let contexto:NSManagedObjectContext = appDelegado.managedObjectContext

    class ViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource {
        @IBOutlet weak var myTable: UITableView!

        var textFeild:UITextField!

        var arreglo:[String] = [String]()
        var arreglosId:[String] = [String]()
        //var tamano:Int = 0

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


            let entityMarca =  NSEntityDescription.entityForName("MARCA", inManagedObjectContext: contexto)

            let newMarca = NSManagedObject(entity: entityMarca!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
            newMarca.setValue("NISSAN", forKey: "nombre")


            let newMarca1 = NSManagedObject(entity: entityMarca!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
            newMarca1.setValue("FIAT", forKey: "nombre")
            //print(newMarca1)

            let newMarca2 = NSManagedObject(entity: entityMarca!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
            newMarca2.setValue("BWM", forKey: "nombre")
            //print(newMarca2)

            let newMarca3 = NSManagedObject(entity: entityMarca!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
            newMarca3.setValue("FORD", forKey: "nombre")
            //print(newMarca3)

            let newMarca4 = NSManagedObject(entity: entityMarca!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
            newMarca4.setValue("CHEVROLET", forKey: "nombre")
            //print(newMarca4)

            let newMarca5 = NSManagedObject(entity: entityMarca!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
            newMarca5.setValue("FERRARI", forKey: "nombre")
            //print(newMarca5)
            do{
                //Inserto(guardo) en BD
                try contexto.save()
                //print(newMarca.description)
                print("Insertando marca")
            }catch {
                print("Aqui hubo un error:-----\(error)")
            }


            arreglo.removeAll()

            let consulta = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MARCA")
            if let resultados = try?contexto.executeFetchRequest(consulta) {

                for x in resultados {
                    arreglo.append("\(x.valueForKey("nombre")!)")
                    arreglosId.append("\(x.objectID)")
                }
            }



        }
        override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)


        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let celda = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
            celda.textLabel?.text = arreglo[indexPath.row]
            return celda
        }

        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return arreglo.count
        }


        func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
            var identificador = arreglosId[indexPath.row]
            var valorTexto:String =  ""
    //        
      // let newMarca = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MARCA", //inManagedObjectContext: contexto)
       // newMarca.setValue("x", forKey: "nombre")
         //   _ = try? contexto.obtainPermanentIDsForObjects([newMarca]);

         let alerta = UIAlertController(title:"Agrega modelo", message: "Registra un nuevo modelo ha esta marca", preferredStyle:.Alert)
            alerta.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler(configuredTextField)
            let action =  UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: {
                (alerta)->Void in
                 valorTexto = self.textFeild.text!
                print(valorTexto)
                let consulta = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MARCA")
                /**========= PROBLEMA*/
                consulta.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF = %@", NSManagedObject(self.arreglosId[indexPath.row]))
                 print("consulta \(consulta)")
                if let results =  try? contexto.executeFetchRequest(consulta) where results.count > 0 {
                    for x in results {
                    print("valor de x  \n\(x)")
                    }
                }else{
                   print("No hay registros")
                }
            })
           alerta.addAction(action)
           presentViewController(alerta, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }

        /**Metodo para configurar el textField  el textField*/
        func configuredTextField(text:UITextField! ){
            text.placeholder = "Descripción"
            textFeild = text
        }
    }
```

**imagen 1**
[image]

**imagen 2**
[image]

Comment: Una cosa importante por el tema de que no nos sangren los ojos al leer, 'Registra un nuevo modelo ha esta marca' está mal escrito, seria 'Registra un nuevo modelo **a** esta marca'. De nada comunidad

Answer (score 1):

La relación en CoreData hay que tomarla como si fueran objetos. A fin de cuentas lo que intenta hacer CoreData es unos registros de SQLite3 se traten como si fueran objetos, y despreocuparnos de relaciones, borrados, etc. Lo primero seria ver como tienes el modelo de datos creado. Tienes una marca que puede tener 1 o varios modelos (relación 1-N), y con respecto al borrado, si eliminas una marca deberías eliminar todos los modelos pero si eliminas un modelo deberías seguir teniendo la marca (Delete rule Cascade o Nullify)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Te creas las entidades y configuras que la relación modelo es "type To Many" y "delete rule Cascade"
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ahora te creas la inversa, cuando quieres manejar un modelo

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pues para relacionar entre modelo y marca es muy sencillo. Tienes que tener creado un modelo marca, eso lo estas haciendo con

```
let newMarca = NSManagedObject(entity: entityMarca!,        insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
        newMarca.setValue("NISSAN", forKey: "nombre")
```

Pues ahora, newMarca también tiene newMarca.modelo. Lo que tienes que hacer es crear el modelo y relacionarlo como si fuera un objeto, CoreData para el resto

```
let newModelo = NSManagedObject(entity: entityModelos!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: contexto)
        newModeloCoche.setValue("ModeloX", forKey: "modeloCoche")
```

Y la magia viene cuando haces:
    newMarca.modelo = newModelo

A la pregunta que haces sobre porque no aparece la marca, es porque es un fault. Es una forma de trabajar de core data. Significa que hay algo, pero como no lo has pedido pues Core Data no ha perdido tiempo ni recursos en ir a buscarlo. Si lo necesitas entonces lo buscara. Si buscas en la entidad marcas, podras ver que hay un fault en los modelos, están ahí, pero solo has buscado marcas. en cuanto pidas sacar los modelos, entonces Core Data accede al disco y te da los modelos. Si tienes muchos datos, también podrá suceder que en un momento determinado los registros mas antiguos te los pase a fault, asi libera memoria. Asi que por los fault no te asustes

Comment: Este es mi relacion c on las entidades

Comment: Mira este es mi código para buscar Cierta marca, Dentro la entidad f MODELO